# How to copy a row and insert in same table and also update specific column with user values in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

In MySQL, I am trying to copy a row in the same table and also increment the primary key and further update a column at the same time.

For example:

```
 1   |   Test1    |  VALUE1 |
 2   |   Test1    |  VALUE2 |
```

NOTE: I was able to figure out to copy a record and insert it as a new record but I cannot figure out how to update the data at the same time.

UPDATE: I am using something  like this:

```
Insert into table(col1, col2)
select c1, c2
from table
where id = 1
```

Comment: What SQL statement are you using currently?

Comment: I have put the code i am using currently in the update section.

Comment: I tried explicitly placing a value inside the select field that I want to insert in an updated row. It works fine but just wanted to make sure if that is the right way to do it or is there any other way to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a separate update.
Use the value `'VALUE2'` in the `select` statement for `col2`:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, 'VALUE2' 
FROM tablename 
WHERE id = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bff541a3451f941ea152ed52822b7d2).

Comment: if want to insert all data?